# Check Constraint - how to make Check on the same parameters in the table?

Tags: sql-server, check-constraint

I have table calls '`Users`' and there is `UserID` there.

I have also table calls UsersFriends that look like:

```
create table UsersFriends
(   
UserID int references Users(UserID),
FriendID int references Users(UserID), 
primary key(UserID,FriendID)
)
```

As you see, `UserID` and `FriendID` are references from `Users(UserID).`

I want to make sure that there is no enrty like: (1,1) because can't be friend of himself.
So, I tried to make Check but isn't..
I tried to do like this:

```
create table UsersFriends
(   
User1ID int references Users(UserID),
FriendID int references Users(UserID) CHECK (FriendID in (select u.UserID from Users u where      
u.UserID!= User1ID)),
primary key(User1ID,FriendID)
)
```

But I've got error:

```
Msg 1046, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.
```

Someone can help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: I removed the mysql tag because the syntax is only SQL Server and MySQL doesn't support check constraints anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining the `check` constraint inline and moreover subqueries are not allowed. You need to define the constraint at table level like below

```
create table UsersFriends
(   
UserID int references Users(UserID),
FriendID int references Users(UserID), 
primary key(UserID,FriendID),
CONSTRAINT CK_nested_friend check(UserID <> FriendID)
);
```

In case need a demo, see here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1e405

Comment: Hi @Rahul. 
I've got error:
    Msg 1767, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
    Foreign key 'FK__UsersFrie__UserI__5BE2A6F2' references invalid                                 
    table 'Users'.
    Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
    Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Comment: @Zvi, do you have a table called `users`? if yes, then you shouldn't get this error.